# Links not working and text is unselectable

Tags: html, css

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <img id="circle" src="circle.png" alt="circle"/>
        <div class="menu">
        <ul class="menu">
                <a href="#">
                <li id="menu" style="margin-left: 39%;">Home</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                <li id="menu" style="margin-left: 46%;">About</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                <li id="menu" style="margin-left: 53%;">Contact</li>
                </a>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="http://www.google.com"><img id="src" style="margin-right: 6%" src="src.png" /></a>
        <img id="ham" src="ham.png" style="margin-right: 2%" alt="ham"/>
        <img id="smpline" src="smpline.png" style="margin-left: 5%;" alt="smpline"/>
        <div class="welcome">
            <p id="big">Web Design</p>
            <p id="sml">
                Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris <br />
                condimentum , ut fermentum massa justo sit amet <br />
                erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit <br />
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

        <img id="lowerfoto" src="lower.png" alt="lower"/>
        <div class="head">
            <img id="fteweit" src="fterwit.png" alt="white"/>
            <ul class="head">
                <li id="head" style="padding-left: 10%;">FOLLOW US</li>
                <li id="head" style="padding-left: 30%;">GET TO KNOW US</li>
                <li id="head" style="padding-left: 50%;">LOCATIONS</li>
                <li id="head" style="padding-left: 70%;">OUR MISSION</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="under">
                <li id="under" style="padding-left: 10%;">
                    <a href="http://twitter.com">Twitter</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://facebook.com">Faceboook</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://linkedin.com">Linkedin</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://pinterest.com">Pinterest</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://youtube.com">YouTube</a> <br />
                </li>
                <li id="under" style="padding-left: 30%;">
                    <a href="http://twitter.com">About</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://facebook.com">Policies</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://linkedin.com">Careers</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://pinterest.com">Press</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://youtube.com">Developers</a> <br />
                </li>
                <li id="under" style="padding-left: 50%;">
                    <a href="http://twitter.com">Detroit</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://facebook.com">London</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://linkedin.com">Florida</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://pinterest.com">Las Vegas</a> <br />
                    <a href="http://youtube.com">California</a> <br />
                </li>
                <li id="under" style="padding-left: 70%;">
                    Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris <br />
                    condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet <br />
                    risus. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus <br />
                    posuere velit aliquet. Praesent commodo cursus magna, <br />
                    vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Sed posuere consectetur <br />
                </li>
            </ul>

            <img id="fterblk" src="fterblk.png" alt="black" />
            <p style="text-align: center center; position: absolute; top: 285%; left: 50%;color:white;  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">Copyright 2015-2016 @renkj</p>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
html{
    min-height: 100%; margin: 0;
}
body { min-height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.menu li {
      display: inline-block;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      position: absolute;
      top: 5.3%;
}
.header {
    background: url("bghero.png") no-repeat;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    height: 200%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 70%;
    src: url('Montserrat-bold.otf') format('truetype');
}
#circle{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2%;
    top: 4%;
}
#big{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Times New Roman;
    font-size: 900%;
    top: 40%;
    color: white;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;

}
#sml{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Times New Roman;
    font-size: 150%;
    top: 73%;
    color: white;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
}
#smpline{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    height: 0.2%;
    width: 90%;
}
#ham{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6%;
    right:0%;
}
#src{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5.8%;
    right:0%;
}
#menu1{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    right: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5.3%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
}
#menu2{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    top: 5.3%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
    position: absolute;
}
#menu3{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    top: 5.3%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
}

#lowerfoto{
    height: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
#fteweit{
    height: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
#fterblk{
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
}
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-family: Montserrat;
   position: absolute;
   top: 245%;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
.head li {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 248%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

}
.under li {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-style: italic;
    position: absolute;
    top: 255%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-style: none;
    color: #565656;
    z-index: auto;
}
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: #565656;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: #565656;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: #565656;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: #565656;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

(Don't mind the picutres. They aren't appearing because they're not in the jsfiddle. just look at the part of Follow us and below, Get to know us and below, Locations and below and Our Mission and below.

the thing is, that the text in the lower part of the web is unselectable and I cant click on the link, because it is not working for some reason.

Any suggestions on what I should do?
THANKS!

Comment: Always post relevant code in the question itself. Or use [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **.under li** elements has:

```
padding-left: 70%;
```

Change it to

```
margin-left: 70%;
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4eyg8npz/1/)

Also it's not correct to use:

```
            <li id="under" style="margin-left: 30%;">
                ...
            </li>
            <li id="under" style="margin-left: 50%;">
                ...
            </li>
```

ID — unique value, you must use classes for non-unique elements.